# Bluestacks installation does not start after extracting

Tags: bluestacks

My Bluestacsk2 installation does not pop-up after extracting. Just nothing happens after that window. I tried disabling antivirus programs and running it as administrator. My system fulfils the system requirements:

Windows 10 Pro, 4 GB Ram.
Version: BlueStacks2_native_8e68b6e001e5a05ff01c3f89c5790f9d

I also have the latest version of Directx and .NET framework. My graphic card is up to date and works very well.

This problem occurs only for the Bluestacks 2. I can setup the previous beta version. I tried both win7 and win10 versions for Bluestacks2 but they are not starting to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I don't have enough space in C drive. But it was really annoying that Bluestacks does not warn me about this. I had several gigabytes in C, but I have been able to install it properly after I removed 10 gb of data from there. (I don't think you need to remove such big data)